# Looking for Name of Common Website Error Pattern

Tags: session, cookies

Is there a term that describes a website that is designed to assume only one browser tab exists per session?  An example failure case is when modifying a hotel reservation:

1. User opens new tab A with reservation X.  Internally, website sets "current reservation = X".
2. User opens new tab B with reservation Y.  Internally, website sets "current reservation = Y".
3. User clicks "Cancel" on tab A (reservation X).  Internally, website processes "cancel current reservation" which erroneously cancels reservation Y.

Several prominent websites exhibit this failure pattern, including Hilton,  Frontier Airlines, and Amazon Payments.